# Query regarding the continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Background:** (From the definition of Homeomorphism in *Topology*, by Munkres )

Let $X$ and $Y$ represent topological spaces and 
$$f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$$
be a bijective function. Then if $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous functions, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

**Question:**

(1) Would it suffice to say that if $f$ is a bijective, continuous function then $f$ is a homeomorphism?

(1.b) If not, when does it ever happen that $f$ is a continuous, bijective function and $f^{-1}$ is not also a continuous function?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/122013/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to question $1$ is no. Let $X$ be a set and $\tau$, $\tau'$ two topologies on $X$ with $\tau'$ strictly coarser than $\tau$. Then $\operatorname{id} : (X, \tau) \to (X, \tau')$ is a continuous bijection, but its inverse is not continuous.

Comment: I think @JonasMeyer is correct, but I see what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: This is a nice class of examples.  It arises for example when considering the norm and weak topologies on a Banach space.

Answer (score 4):

1. It's not sufficient. There are counterexamples.
2. If the map fails to be open, for example: $\theta\mapsto e^{\theta i}$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. The domain is not compact and the range is, so it is not a homeomorphism. But it is easy to check that this is a continuous bijection.