# The map $f$ from $[0,1)$ to $S^{1}$ is not a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> Proposition:
> Let $f:\left [ 0,1 \right ) \rightarrow S^{1}$ be given by $f\left ( x \right )=x$.
> Then, f is not a homeomorphism.

I do understand the proof. What I really mean is, I do not understand the theorems and motivation to which the author is making at each juncture of his proof.

> Proof:
>
> Consider $\left [ 0,1 \right )$ as a subset of both $\left [ 0,1 \right )$ and $S^{1}$.
> In the first case, $\left [ 0,1 \right )=\left ( \frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right )\cap \left [ 0,1 \right )$
> so $\left [ 0,\frac{1}{2} \right )$ is open in the subspace topology on $\left [ 0,1 \right )$.
> On the other hand, let $\pi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^{1}$ be the projection map defined $\pi\left ( x \right )=\left [ x \right ]$,
> then $\pi^{-1}\left [ 0,1 \right )=\cup _{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left [ n,n+\frac{1}{2} \right )$
> which is clearly not open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
> Hence, $\left [ 0,\frac{1}{2} \right )$ is not open in the quotient topology on $S^{1}$

A step-by-step clear explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know continuous image of a compact space is compact?

Comment: No I don't. Does this falls under topology? If so, the notes hasn't yet covered this portion.

Comment: Yes it does fall under elementary point set topology. Assuming the result can you see that $[0,1)$ and $S^1$ are not homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes. Because $S^{1}$ has a different cardinality to [0,1). So bijection does not hold.@VictorBarg

Comment: Really? What is the cardinality of $S^1$ and $[0,1)$?

Comment: @VictorBarg If one were to map each element in S^{1} to that in [0,1), there would not be a bijective map. Or am I confused?
Edit: I just checked that they do have the same cardinality. I apologise for my lack of formal education in real analysis.

Comment: I think you're confused,cardinality of both sets are uncountable.But since $S^1$ is compact and $[0,1)$ is not compact hence they can not be homeomorphic by the result i mentioned.

Comment: It will be more helpful to return to this section after I've read up on compactness and completeness.

Comment: Almost Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122013/a-bijective-map-that-is-not-a-homeomorphism?rq=1